# C++ Checking for duplicates in a string

Tags: c++, string

I have a function `counter(string s1, string s2)` which takes two strings (both size 4) of numbers as its parameters. `s1` is randomly generated while `s2` is user-input.

```
int counter(string s1, string s2){
    int count = 0;
    int i, j;
    if(i != j){
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                if(s2[i] != s2[j] && s2[j] == s1[i]){
                        count += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

What this function does is compare each element of `s2` to `s1`'s. If an element of `s2` is equal to an element of `s1`, provided that they do not have the same index or position, `count` increments by 1. The function, however, encounters problems when `s2` contains duplicates. For example, if `s1 = 1234` and `s2 = 4445`, the output should be `1`, but my program outputs `3`. How should I be able to detect the duplicates in the string?

Forgot to mention this, but s1 (the randomly generated string) has distinct characters.

Comment: What is the intended behavior? Can you provide some examples of input and what you expect the output to be?

Comment: error: 's1' was not declared in this scope

Comment: `if(i != j)` always false

Comment: It might be true.  In the land of uninitialized variables anything is possible.

Comment: `s1 = "1234"`
. If `s2 = "5674"`
`count = 0` since 4 is in the same position for both strings.
. If `s2 = "3131"
`count = 1` since both 1's are not in the same position in s2 as in s1 while one instance of 3 is both in the 3rd position for s1 and s2.

Comment: Edit: the parameter should be `string s1`

Comment: You can, and should, edit the question to add more details like the input/output desired and to fix typos in the code.  Much better than comments.

Comment: Please clarify what an "element" is.  Do you mean individual characters, or some sort of substring?

Comment: My bad, I was thinking of an int array. It's the former, individual characters.

Comment: What happens if s1 = "1212" and s2 = "1313"? Both 1s are out of position - or are they?

Comment: Count would be 0 since count only increments if the characters similar for both s1 and s2 do not have the same position.

Comment: Is this for some kind fo exercise? Because I'm pretty sure the `std::string` class already have an implementation for that.

Comment: Yep! `string::size_type loc = s2.find(s1[i], 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would solve the problem you have when the same letter is present in S2 several times.

```
int counter(string s1, string s2){
    int count = 0;
    int i, j;
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                if(i != j){
                    if(s2[j] == s1[i]){
                            count += 1;
                            break;       // Break out of inner for-loop
                                         // to avoid counting letters twice
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return count;
}
```

However, I'm not sure what you want the program to do in case the same letter is present in S1 several times.

EDIT:
After reading some of the clarifications in the comments, the if-statement should be

```
if(s2[i] != s2[j] && s2[j] == s1[i]){
```

like in the original post.

Comment: I may have not mentioned this but s1 has distinct characters.

Comment: So `s1="1212";` is illegal input that the program does not need to handle. Right?

Comment: Yep. I've taken care of it with the function that generates the random string.

Comment: In that case, I think the `break;` statement will solve your problem. (Together with moving the `if(I != j)` as shown above.)

Answer (score 0):

I dare suggest. But I broke my brain your question =)

```
int counter(string s1, string s2){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); ++i)
    {
        string::size_type loc = s2.find(s1[i], 0);
        while (loc != string::npos)
        {
           if(loc != i) 
               ++count;
           loc = s2.find(s1[i], loc + 1);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add your if condition inside the for loop,

```
int counter(string s1, string s2){
        int count = 0;
        int i, j;
         for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                    if(i!=j && s2[j] == s1[i]){
                            count += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect duplicate elements by implementing **Levenshtein distance** algorithms.

```
 int levenshtein(const char *s, int ls, const char *t, int lt){
    int a, b, c;

    /* if either string is empty, difference is inserting all chars 
     * from the other
     */
    if (!ls) return lt;
    if (!lt) return ls;

    /* if last letters are the same, the difference is whatever is
     * required to edit the rest of the strings
     */
    if (s[ls] == t[ls])
            return levenshtein(s, ls - 1, t, lt - 1);

    /* else try:
     *      changing last letter of s to that of t; or
     *      remove last letter of s; or
     *      remove last letter of t,
     * any of which is 1 edit plus editing the rest of the strings
     */
    a = levenshtein(s, ls - 1, t, lt - 1);
    b = levenshtein(s, ls,     t, lt - 1);
    c = levenshtein(s, ls - 1, t, lt    );

    if (a > b) a = b;
    if (a > c) a = c;
    return a + 1;}
```